Unsupported class file major version 65" error
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not open cp_settings generic class cache for settings file 'D:\work\flutter\event_trace\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\HomePC.gradle\caches\8.0\scripts\8ju52g7d2hqvl85b219kdzjzv).


BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'BuildScript' Unsupported class file major version 65


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 47s
┌─ Flutter Fix ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐ │ [!] Your project's Gradle version is incompatible with the Java version that Flutter is using   │ │ for Gradle.                                                                                     │ │                                                                                                 │ │ If you recently upgraded Android Studio, consult the migration guide at                         │ │ https://flutter.dev/to/to/java-gradle-incompatibility.                                          │ │                                                                                                 │ │ Otherwise, to fix this issue, first, check the Java version used by Flutter by running flutter  │ │ doctor --verbose.                                                                               │ │                                                                                                 │ │ Then, update the Gradle version specified in                                                    │ │ D:\work\flutter\event_trace\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to be compatible   │ │ with that Java version. See the link below for more information on compatible Java/Gradle       │ │ versions:                                                                                       │ │ https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#java                               │ │                                                                                                 │ │

What do I need to put in place? The app is not building at all

Major version 65 is the class version used for Java 21. This means if you're building or running your application with a lower version that this you'll get the error you see - so try to find a version of the library that supports an older Java version or upgrade yours.

What is your java version? run java --version to see

@Thomas Given the error talks about "semantic analysis", it might also be that the OP is using Java 21, and whatever does this semantic analysis doesn't support class file version 65, so it can't process the files produced by the compile phase.

have you updated the latest version of android studio?

This question is similar to: How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You need to upgrade gradle version according to Java version compatibility in latest Android Studio.
Follow this link to update gradle version / migration guide :- https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/android-java-gradle-migration-guide

If you are using java version lower than 20, you should use gradle version lower than 8.0. according to this
So you need to decrease your gradle version, to do this, open
/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
from your project folder and change distributionUrl to gradle-7.6-bin if you're using java 19, or gradle-7.3-bin if you're using java 17:
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-bin.zip


That lists the minimum Gradle version you need for a Java version, not the maximum Gradle version. For example, Gradle 8.10 works with Java 8 or higher (Gradle 9, not yet released, will require Java 17 or higher).
